# How do I change the font selection in a GMail compose window from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I often mention code in my e-mails, which I like to make visually distinct from the rest of the text. It's a huge pain to do this with the current UI, though.

I want to make a Chrome extension which adds a keyboard shortcut to toggle the font in the GMail compose window to 'Courier New' and back to 'Sans Serif'. This seems relatively hard since all the JS code is obfuscated.

Comment: This would be a useful feature - heck, I'd use it – but this is not really a constructive question for SO.

Comment: Any particular reason why? It's definitely a technical questions. I think it would be even less appropriate at the GMail product forums, which is the other placed I thought of asking, since those aren't really for programmers.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov not a programming problem, as it's either about how to use gmail's interface or "how do I build a chrome extension" - either of which aren't on topic/appropriate here.

Comment: I updated my answer with a bookmarklet.

Comment: @AD7six: This is only incidentally related to Chrome Extensions (the accepted answer uses a bookmarklet). The FAQ states that "if your question generally covers: [...] 3) software tools commonly used by programmers [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question". My question clearly falls in this category.

Comment: @MattBall: Your flagged the question because it "cannot be reasonably answered in its current form", but it was answered quite well below.

Comment: Well, while the question doesn't contain any code, it is definitely about *programming*. Voted for reopen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't cover toggling the menu, but you can simply edit the DOM of the email body directly. GMail seems to use `<font face='courier new, monospace'>...</font>` to set the font, so you can just do it like [this bookmarklet](http://jsbin.com/ilopej/3/quiet).

```
javascript:(function(){var selection=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);var selectedText=selection.extractContents();var font=document.createElement('font');font.face='courier new, monospace';font.appendChild(selectedText);selection.insertNode(font);})();
```

Comment: I suppose it would be nice to add toggling, but this is definitely an acceptable solution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly with Google Inbox.